# Edit textbox and submit in HTML/ JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a textbox in my HTML file. It is basically a comment box. I want it to function such that it is in disabled state normally. But when someone clicks a 'EDIT' button it should allow them to modify the value in the textbox. On clicking the EDIT button, I would either like to display a new SUBMIT button or change the EDIT button to SUBMIT button itself.

Can someone give me some sample code. I know the code would be quite easy, but I am very bad with JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520/is-there-a-better-alternative-to-rentacoder-for-developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<textarea id='disText' disabled="disabled"></textarea>
<button id='disAble'>Edit</button>
```

Js:

```
$('button#disAble').on('click', function(){
    $('textarea#disText').prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).text('submit');
    //submit stuff
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DKtxn/

Comment: Note that Neal's answer requires the jQuery library, so you must reference that in your code. A line like this in your `<head>` tags would suffice: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @gibberish the OP requested jQuery... see the tags in the question....

Comment: @Neal What about something like this? (building off your original) http://jsfiddle.net/DKtxn/1/

Comment: @Neal Okay...I was just trying to differentiate between editing and submitting. Sheesh

Comment: @Ian ahhh sorry i thought you were the other commentor. that looks cool ^_^

Comment: And @Neal you'll find that Giberrish was only adding help to your answer, not commenting on its worth. o_O